# Problems with gecko_spellcheck in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to prevent TinyMCE disabling gecko spellcheck. I've added `gecko_spellcheck : true` to config. It works fine, but when I type a new paragraph all highlights of previous paragraph are gone. Some illustrations:

[image: First paragraph]

### [image: Second paragraph]

When I make right click on textarea and disable/enable spellchecking, all of errors are highlighted. How can I make TinyMCE always to highlight errors?

Comment: I've checked tumblr.com, they have the same problem. Perhaps, there is no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that can be resolved.
If you reset the tinymce iframe body everything that is spelled incorrectly gets underlined.

You may use this `ed.getBody.innerHTML = ed.getBody.innerHTML;` to make it work.

Comment: place this code at the desired places in your code or use the tinymce init param "setup" and define a handler for an event that should trigger the spellcheck.