# Get TinyMCE - gecko_spellcheck - to work on initial content load

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want the spell check that the gecko_spellcheck provides to work on the initial content on TinyMCE.  The spell check will work okay with new typed information, but it will not have the spell check with content already in the editor.  Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

I've tried, specific for TinyMCE, following the path given in this advice - [Problems with gecko_spellcheck in TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8634106/1564167).

I've tried putting this code into numerous events in the TinyMCE editor -- such as, onPostReder, onInit, onSaveContent.

Thank you.

I'm trying to avoid the button-style spell checking that's been [seen](http://ondotnet.deap.nu/2009/01/implementing-tinymce-spellchecker-with.html) around on the web.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to reset the content oninit

```
var editor = tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
editor.setContent(editor.getContent());
```

This triggers the spellcheck functionality of your browser.

Comment: I tried it on - ed.onInit.add() - but it did not work.  I got it to work briefly on the $(windows).load(), turns out you have to reset the content after the editor is fully loaded, but it's kind of inconsistent.  If you have any other ideas that would be great.  Thanks for the feedback!